# Protect files in directory using authentication script in php/apache

Tags: php, apache, authentication

I'm looking for a way to tell Apache that if there is a request for a file from a certain directory it should first run a php script to verify if the user is logged in.
I know I could put the directory outside of the docroot and let a php script handle the authentication and file downloads, but because these are flash files that try to open other flash files it has to be a directory in the docroot, and the files should not have to be send by the php script.
In the old setup we were using mod_auth_script(http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-auth-script/), but as that is a rather obscure apache module I'd rather have a more common solution if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use .htaccess and mod_rewrite to redirect requests to php script. Try some googling and you will find lots of examples.

.htaccess contents example:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ([0-9a-z-_]+)\.swf$ checkForAuth.php?&file=$1 [L]
```

This will call checkForAuth.php when someone will try to access *.swf file. In checkForAuth.php you need to check your session, read contents from $_GET['file'], set correct headers (content-type for flash) and output contents of requested SWF file.

Comment: well I don't want to redirect, because the flash files need to be accessible directly. Apache should just check if the user can access the directory (using a PHP based authentication that checks the session) and that's it. Otherwise the start flash file can't pull in the other flash files

Comment: Redirect will not be seen on user side. URL will stay the same but content will be given thru PHP file which will check session.

Comment: ah right, so the flash files will still just request /files/foo.swf.. is it too much to ask for a link?

Comment: This is not a good way for website performance (we have to readfile in php). There are Apache server level Authentication and Authorization directives for httpd.conf and .htaccess. We can combine AuthType Form with AuthFormProvider dbd (database driver) and with DBDriver mysql and DBDParams "..." and ... then we just need a mysql table keeps the auth un pass of upload or download files. The credentials must use in the pages(download or upload and set in the dbtable having and expire time to compare against mysql timestamp). That's it. Just simple :)